# Crypto++ library and dependency error

Tags: c++, dll, encryption, dependencies

I downloaded and built successfully the Crypto++ library. Looking at it with [depends.exe](http://www.dependencywalker.com), I see the following:

[image]

The "call hierarchy" to the problematic external module seems to be (from depends.exe) :

- `CRYPTOPP.DLL`
- `ADVAPI32.DLL`
- `USER32.DLL`
- `POWRPROF.DLL`
- `SETUPAPI.DLL`
- `USERENV.DLL`
- `GPSVC.DLL`

In the Crypto++ source code, I noticed in `osrng.h`, there is a

```
#pragma comment(lib, "advapi32.lib")
```

Anyone could help me understand why there is an unresolved external module from the DLL? I can't use it because of that.

Comment: have you tried running your program? what error message is displayed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a problem using the library, it's certainly not due to that dependency missing. Note that the hierarchy you listed include advapi32.dll and user32.dll. Both are DLLs directly needed by pretty much every single Windows program, so they clearly can't be unusable.

The hourglass next to the icons in depends.exe means that the DLLs are [delay loaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790.aspx). A delay loaded DLL isn't loaded until a function from it is actually called, so it's entirely possible to delay load from DLLs that doesn't exist and still have a working program.

Comment: Hi and thanks, "so it's entirely possible to delay load from DLLs that doesn't exist and still have a working program", What do you mean by that, isn't the linker verifying that all called libraries exist on compilation? Also, I agree that from depends.exe, it looks like there are delay loaded DLLs, however in VS2010 if I check the CryptoPP project's property page, in the Linker->Input section, I see no value in "Delay Loaded Dlls"...where else could I find if the project is using delay loading?

Comment: The linker never verifies that DLLs exist, whether you delay load or not. It only checks for .lib files. When an EXE or a DLL is loaded, Windows checks that all DLLs that it links to statically exist.

Comment: The reason there are no "Delay Loaded Dlls" listed in CryptoPP is that CryptoPP itself doesn't have any delay loaded DLLs. cryptopp.dll links (e.g.) advapi32.dll without delay loading, so cryptopp.dll will fail to load immediately if advapi32.dll is missing. In the same way advapi32.dll will fail to load if user32.dll is missing. But (e.g.) userenv.dll will NOT fail to load if gpsvc.dll is missing.

Comment: thank you very much for your input...however I am still not sure what is the problem and what to do. I agree that it's pretty much impossible that cryptopp.dll is incorrect, but what can I do so that when I inspect the dll with depends.exe, it would give no more errors..?

Comment: Try viewing notepad.exe or almost anything else included in Windows with Dependency Walker. You will see the same warnings there.

Comment: Hi, I finally found out the problem : the library cryptopp.dll MUST be placed in the SysWOW64. Before, it was in the same folder as my program calling it. Do you know why it wasn't working with the library in the same directory? Thanks!